# How do I get a list of files that have been added to the SVN since a certain date?

Tags: svn

I only want a list of files that have been added (not ones that have been modified) since a certain date. Is there an easy way to do this?

**Answer**: Here's what ended up working for me, thanks guys!

> svn log -v -r{2008-10-1}:HEAD svn://path.to.repo/ | grep "^   A" | grep ".java" | sort -u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
svn log -v -r{2008-10-1}:HEAD | grep "^   A"
```

Comment: thanks, good idea...just got to modify that search pattern a bit (the way you wrote it would return checkin comment lines with the word "A" in them.

Comment: Yes, but a capital A with spaces around it is rather rare. You could use "^    A"

Comment: wouldn't have been that rare. A good example would be this sentence. ;-) But yeah, the circumflex did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you use 'svn log -v -q' you get the filename and no log messages. This is a little bit faster over http:// and svn:// as the log messages are not transferred to you.

svn log --xml -v -q gives you the same information but in easy to parse xml. (This handles all corner cases on strange file names for you).

Answer (score 1):

Something like

`svn log -v -r {"2008-01-01"}:HEAD . | grep ' A ' | sort -u`

should get you going...

Answer (score 0):

you can try following command,

```
svn log -r '{2013-09-09}:HEAD'
```

Here you get all the revision details from date 9/9/2013